# Test Method fails with Log Error

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j, morphia

I've written a test Method. In this project I use Morphia for MongoDB. But when I start the Method I get the follow Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.log(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.info(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:166)
at com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:71)
at com.mongodb.connection.SingleServerCluster.<init>(SingleServerCluster.java:45)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:85)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:670)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:656)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:278)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:274)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:174)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:151)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:141)
at de.meinTellerchen.utils.mongoDB.connection.MongoDBCon.<init>(MongoDBCon.java:65)
at de.meinTellerchen.ingredient.service.IngredientRestService.dataBaseConnection(IngredientRestService.java:34)
at de.meinTellerchen.ingredient.service.IngredientRestService.<init>(IngredientRestService.java:22)
at de.meinTellerchen.ingredient.service.IngredientRestServiceTest.test001_WriteIngredient(IngredientRestServiceTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The Method in this Test creates an Object and saves it in a MongoDB with Morphia.

```
    @Test
public void test001_WriteIngredient() {
    Ingredient ingredient = generateIngredient();
    IngredientRestService ingredientRestService = new IngredientRestService();
    assertNotNull(ingredient);
    Response response = ingredientRestService.writeIngredient(ingredient);
    assertNotNull(response);

}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I don't use Logger.

Comment: seems like log4j jar version issue. check your classpath

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the version of log4j and slf4j.
Add below mentioned jars in your classpath :
log4j
slf4j-simple
jcl-over-slf4j
slf4j-api
slf4j-log4j12 with appropriate versions
or use maven to handle your dependencies.

Example of Compatible versions of jars:
1) log4j-1.2.15.jar
2) slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
3) commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
4) logback-classic-1.0.0.jar
5) logback-core-1.0.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

The dependent jar of slf4j is missing in your classpath.

Please open the mongodriver jar available in your system and see the meta-inf/MANIFEST.MF file and add the required jars mentioned in Import-Package:section.

**Example:**
**Mongodb java driver 3.2.1** requires following dependent jars.

```
Import-Package: javax.xml.bind,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.ma
 nagement,javax.net,javax.net.ssl,javax.security.sasl,javax.security.a
 uth.callback,org.ietf.jgss,io.netty.bootstrap;resolution:=optional;ve
 rsion="[4.0,5)",io.netty.buffer;resolution:=optional;version="[4.0,5)
 ",io.netty.channel;resolution:=optional;version="[4.0,5)",io.netty.ch
 annel.nio;resolution:=optional;version="[4.0,5)",io.netty.channel.soc
 ket;resolution:=optional;version="[4.0,5)",io.netty.channel.socket.ni
 o;resolution:=optional;version="[4.0,5)",io.netty.handler.ssl;resolut
 ion:=optional;version="[4.0,5)",io.netty.handler.timeout;resolution:=
 optional;version="[4.0,5)",io.netty.util.concurrent;resolution:=optio
 nal;version="[4.0,5)",org.slf4j;resolution:=optional;version="[1.7,2)
 "
```